# SPARQL: slow processing of result of subquery

Tags: group-by, sparql, rdf

I'm currently learning SPARQL, and I can't wrap my head around why what seems to me like a very straightforward query takes a large amount to time. I'm trying to count the number of articles per author in a journal, using the OpenCitations project (SPARQL endpoint https://opencitations.net/sparql, I also downloaded a dump of an earlier version).

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX pro: <http://purl.org/spar/pro/>
PREFIX frbr: <http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/core#>
PREFIX fabio: <http://purl.org/spar/fabio/>

SELECT $author (COUNT($author) as $cnt) WHERE {
    # narrowing down journal down to articles (over issues and volumes)
    $jnl a fabio:Journal;
       dcterms:title "Nature" . 
    $volm frbr:partOf $jnl . 
    $issue frbr:partOf $volm .
    $artcl frbr:partOf $issue . 

    # selecting author
    ?artcl pro:isDocumentContextFor ?artcl_atrbts . 
    ?artcl_atrbts pro:isHeldBy ?author.

    # making sure that author is a person
    $author foaf:familyName $y .
}

GROUP BY $author
ORDER BY DESC($cnt)
LIMIT 10
```

This works as expected, and takes around 3 seconds on the dump, and maybe 5 on the OpenCitations endpoint.

However now I also want to get the actual names of the authors, so my idea was to use the previous query as a subquery:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX pro: <http://purl.org/spar/pro/>
PREFIX frbr: <http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/core#>
PREFIX fabio: <http://purl.org/spar/fabio/>


SELECT $author $last_name $cnt WHERE {
    $author foaf:familyName $last_name. 

    {
    SELECT $author (COUNT($author) as $cnt) WHERE {

    $jnl a fabio:Journal;
    dcterms:title "Nature" . 
    $volm frbr:partOf $jnl . 
    $issue frbr:partOf $volm .

    $artcl frbr:partOf $issue . 
    ?artcl pro:isDocumentContextFor ?artcl_trbts . 
    ?artcl_trbts pro:isHeldBy ?author.
    $author foaf:familyName $y .
    }

    GROUP BY $author
    ORDER BY DESC($cnt)
    LIMIT 10
    }
}
ORDER BY DESC($cnt)
```

This now takes around 15 seconds on the dump, (more than a minute on the online endpoint), even though it seems to me all it is doing is looking up the 10 values of the givenName for the authors. If I include the first name (foaf:givenName) as well, the query can take even longer. Furthermore, when I select names without grouping by author, it executes within a split second:

```
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX pro: <http://purl.org/spar/pro/>
PREFIX frbr: <http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/core#>
PREFIX fabio: <http://purl.org/spar/fabio/>

SELECT $author $first_name $last_name WHERE {

    $jnl a fabio:Journal;
    dcterms:title "Nature" . 
    $volm frbr:partOf $jnl . 
    $issue frbr:partOf $volm .

    $artcl frbr:partOf $issue . 
    ?artcl pro:isDocumentContextFor ?artcl_trbts . 
    ?artcl_trbts pro:isHeldBy ?author.
    $author foaf:familyName $last_name .
    $author foaf:givenName $first_name .
    }
LIMIT 10
```

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why can't you just get the name in your first query?

Comment: thanks for the tip, that works out indeed! I had tried that before but had gotten a "bad aggregate" warning, but you made me realize now how do it properly (all relevant variables in the GROUP BY call, but only one in the COUNT statement). I am however still curious why it takes so long when using subqueries, especially since I might still need them eventually when my queries grow more complicated.

Comment: you're not doing anything wrong. It's just the query optimizer that sometimes has problems. For the current triple store, which is a Blazegraph store you can help the optimizer via query hints:

Comment: `PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> PREFIX pro: <http://purl.org/spar/pro/> PREFIX frbr: <http://purl.org/vocab/frbr/core#> PREFIX fabio: <http://purl.org/spar/fabio/> PREFIX hint: <http://www.bigdata.com/queryHints#>`

Comment: `SELECT $author $last_name $cnt WHERE {      $author foaf:familyName $last_name.       hint:Prior hint:runLast true .     {     SELECT $author (COUNT($author) as $cnt) WHERE {      $jnl a fabio:Journal;     dcterms:title "Nature" .      $volm frbr:partOf $jnl .      $issue frbr:partOf $volm .      $artcl frbr:partOf $issue .      ?artcl pro:isDocumentContextFor ?artcl_trbts .      ?artcl_trbts pro:isHeldBy ?author.     $author foaf:familyName $y .     }      GROUP BY $author     ORDER BY DESC($cnt)     LIMIT 10     }   } ORDER BY DESC($cnt)`

Comment: *"all relevant variables in the GROUP BY call"* — alternatively, `SELECT $author (SAMPLE($y) AS $family_name) ... GROUP BY $author`.

Comment: @swhalemwo - You've found the answer. Now post it for others...